# Se puede realizar una expresion regular de un string? JS

Tags: javascript

El problema mio es que tengo un array con la informacion de la base de datos, le voy mostrando al usuario las coincidencias mientras va ingresando en el input, es decir:

```
tengo en el array:

array = ["manzana, naranja, pera, durazno"]
```

mientras el usuario va ingresando en el input va mostrando las coincidencias, tengo un filtro hecho pero yo estoy usando .match, y punto match es muy generico, es decir si el usuario ingresa la letra n, este te va a retornar manzana, durazno y naranja porque tienen la letra n, hay alguna manera de que solamente devuelva aquellos que inician con n? para asi no tener que mostrar los que no comienzan con n tambien pero lo llevan

Answer (score 1):

Claro que si, puedes usar el [método **`test`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) de la siguiente forma:

```js
    let valores = ['manzana', 'naranja', 'durazno'];
    let patron = /^n/;
    
    for (fruta of valores) {
      console.log(patron.test(fruta))
    }
```

Donde como puedes observar:

- Tengo un vector de valores *string* a evaluar
- Declaro en una variable la expresión regular a buscar, la cual tendrá solo en cuenta los elementos que inicien con n
- Itero los valores y por dentro del ciclo evalúo si el patrón establecido existe en el valor recuperado pro cada vuelta del ciclo.

Posterior si necesitas almacenarlos y recuperar todas las posibles coincidencias, puedes:

- declarar un vector vacio
- Establecer un condicional interno que evalúe si test fue verdadero o falso
- si es verdadero hacemos un push de los elementos recuperados hacia el nuevo vector
- Imprimimos por fuera del ciclo el vector recién llenado

```js
    let valores = ['manzana', 'naranja', 'durazno', 'mango'];
    let patron = /^n/;
    let coincidencias = [];
    
    for (fruta of valores) {
      if (patron.test(fruta)) {
        coincidencias.push(fruta)
      }
    }
    
    console.log(coincidencias)
```

Comment: amigo estoy usandolo pero por alguna razon a mi me da false, sin embargo si cambio /w*/ da true, pero /^w/ da false

Comment: en lo mio hay un w xDDDD, por eso, pero viendo no funciona

Comment: si lo se amigo, en realidad tu codigo lo puedo usar en lo mio, pero por alguna razon no funciona con /^w/, he ido a paginas donde pruebas tu expresion regular y ahi /^w/ funciona, seguire viendo si no, buscare otra manera

Comment: `/w*/` concuerda con cero o más `w`, y como en las cuatro frutas hay cero `w`, concuerda con todas. `/^w/` concuerda con las frutas que empiecen por `w`, o sea ninguna de las cuatro. ¿Por qué estás poniendo una `w`? ¿No lo estarás confundiendo con `\w` que es un metacarácter que concuerda con letra, número o guion bajo?